# Extract text from img tag of bs4.element.Tag

Tags: python, html, image, beautifulsoup, tags

I have the following question to ask.

I have a list of bs4.element.Tags like the list of this image

[image: list of tags]

As you can see there are lots of element that have the tag "a href="/title/...">. However, I don't want to keep all of them. I want only the href tags that are followed from an `<img>` tag. How can I achieve this?

And secondly when I keep only those elements

[image: keep elements with <img> tag]

I would like to keep only the the word inside the title tag. For example in the picture below to keep the "img title = "Gravity" so only the word Gravity.

[image: text to keep]

**LINK OF HTML DOCS:** [HTML Documents for each movie](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RiefMbiPYANeyVugyBT-C4XF0v8MR5D5/view?usp=sharing)

**CODE**

```
from tqdm import tqdm
with open('requests_list_dummy.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    requests_list_dummy = pickle.load(f)

souplist = []

for i in tqdm(requests_list_dummy):
    souplist.append(BeautifulSoup(i.text))

souplist_dummy = souplist

# phase 1

phase_1 = []

for i in tqdm(souplist_dummy):
    phase_1.append(i.find_all('div', {'class':'article', 'id': 'titleRecs'}))

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# phase 2

phase_2 = []

import re
r_one = re.compile(".*title")

for i in tqdm(phase_1):
    for j in i:
        phase_2.append(j.find_all('img'))

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# # phase 3

phase_3 = []

for i in tqdm(range(len(phase_2))):
    phase_3.append(list(map(lambda x: x, phase_2[i][0:12])))

# # phase 4

phase_4 = []

for i in tqdm(phase_3):
    for j in i:
        phase_4.append(j.find_all('title'))
```

Comment: Can you post actual html instead of images?

Comment: you mean `a>img[title]`

Comment: @JackFleeting I don't have the HTML code since it's in Python Notebook.

Comment: @mplungjan I tried to call  .find_all('img', {'title'})..but that had no result

Comment: can't you just copy and paste it?

Comment: @JackFleeting I have attached the code :)

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to paste the html code, the part beginning with `<a href="/title/...>` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following which requires bs4 4.7.1+ and uses `:has` to specify you want `a` tags with `img` child, then adjacent sibling combinator to get next `img` and add in attribute = value selectors to ensure `href` containing specific substring and a `title` attribute. If you know there will always be a `title` attribute you could drop that from the selector.

```
titles = [i['title'] for i in soup.select("a:has(img) + [href*='/title/tt'][title]")]
```